# Exception safety for overlapped Boost coroutines

Tags: c++, exception, boost, boost-asio

The following code spawns 2 functions as Asio handlers (which use Boost.Coroutine under the hood) on the same thread.
Each function throws and catches an exception in such an order so that the code in the catch blocks overlaps due to coroutine context switching, as follows:

```
fn1 throw
fn1 start catch
fn2 throw
fn1 end catch
fn2 end catch
```

And as it turns out (according to the log below), when the fn1's catch ends the exception object from the fn2 is destroyed, and when fn2's catch ends the exception object from fn1 is destroyed.
Effectively this means the catch block must not access its exception object after it was interrupted by other coroutines.
Is this an expected behavior or a bug in the compiler / Boost?
Is it safe at all to use context switching in a catch blocks like that?

GCC 4.8.5, 4.9.2, 8.2.0, Clang 5.0.0, Boost 1.55, 1.66, Linux, x86_64

The test code:

```
#define BOOST_COROUTINES_NO_DEPRECATION_WARNING
#define BOOST_COROUTINE_NO_DEPRECATION_WARNING

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/asio/spawn.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/io_service.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/steady_timer.hpp>

namespace ba = boost::asio;

ba::io_service io_service;

#define LOG_TRACE(x) do { std::cout << x << std::endl; } while (0)

class MyEx: public std::runtime_error {
public:
    MyEx(std::string msg)
        : std::runtime_error(msg)
    {
        LOG_TRACE("MyEx " << msg << " addr=" << (void*)this);
    }
    ~MyEx()
    {
        LOG_TRACE("~MyEx " << what() << " addr=" << (void*)this);
    }
};

void throw_ex(size_t n)
{
    throw MyEx("exception " + std::to_string(n));
}

void sleep_ms(size_t ms, ba::yield_context yield)
{
    ba::steady_timer timer(io_service);
    timer.expires_from_now(std::chrono::milliseconds(ms));
    timer.async_wait(yield);
}

void* curr_ex()
{
    auto ep = std::current_exception();
    return *reinterpret_cast<void**>(&ep);
}

void fn1(ba::yield_context yield)
{
    try {
        sleep_ms(100, yield);
        throw_ex(1);
    }
    catch (const MyEx& e) {
        LOG_TRACE("1: catch start " << e.what() << " curr_ex=" << curr_ex());
        sleep_ms(300, yield);
        LOG_TRACE("1: catch end, curr_ex=" << curr_ex());
    }
}

void fn2(ba::yield_context yield)
{
    try {
        sleep_ms(200, yield);
        throw_ex(2);
    }
    catch (const MyEx& e) {
        LOG_TRACE("2: catch start " << e.what() << " curr_ex=" << curr_ex());
        sleep_ms(300, yield);
        LOG_TRACE("2: catch end, curr_ex=" << curr_ex());
    }
}


int main ()
{
    ba::spawn(io_service, [](ba::yield_context yield){ fn1(yield); });
    ba::spawn(io_service, [](ba::yield_context yield){ fn2(yield); });
    io_service.run();
    return 0;
}
```

The output:

```
MyEx exception 1 addr=0x21fafe0
1: catch start exception 1 curr_ex=0x21fafe0
MyEx exception 2 addr=0x21fb080
2: catch start exception 2 curr_ex=0x21fb080
1: catch end, curr_ex=0x21fb080
~MyEx exception 2 addr=0x21fb080
2: catch end, curr_ex=0x21fafe0
~MyEx exception 1 addr=0x21fafe0
```